# when selecting from a php populated dropdown use the desired data and populate an html table with more php depending on which data was selected

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hello and thanks for coming.

So I have the Category table with "n" values on it, and I have the table Price with "n" duplicated idCategorys (foreign Key) in it.

What I want to do is when selecting a Category from a dropdown menu a Html Table gets populated with all the prices with the Category i've chosen.

So far I've managed to get a dropdown select menu populated with php as follows:

```
<select name="categorias" required id="categorias" >
      <?php $render = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT idCategoria FROM neomixlt_desarrollo.Categorias"); 
       while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($render)) {

        echo "<option value='" . $row1['idCategoria'] . "'>" . $row1['idCategoria'] ."</option>";
   }        
   ?>
        </select>
```

And a table populated as follows

```
<table width="957" border="2" cellspacing="0">
   <tr>
         <th width="98" style="text-align: center">Categoria</th>
        <th width="99" style="text-align: center">Articulo</th>
         <th width="348" style="text-align: center">Precio a Domicilio(bs.)</th>
         <th width="348" style="text-align: center">Precio en Planta(bs.)</th>
         <th width="40" style="text-align: center"></th>
   </tr>
   <?php $render = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM neomixlt_desarrollo.precios_articulo WHERE idCategoria=$link ORDER BY idCategoria DESC ") or die(mysql_error()); ?>
   <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($render)):; ?>
      <tr>
          <td style="text-align: center"><?php echo $row1['idCategoria']; ?></td
          ><td style="text-align: center"><?php echo $row1['idArticulo']; ?></td>
          <td style="text-align: center"><?php echo $row1['precio_domi']; ?></td>
          <td style="text-align: center"><?php echo $row1['precio_plant']; ?></td>
          <td style="text-align: center"><?php echo "<a href=editar_precios.php?pid=$row1[idArticulo]&cid=$row1[idCategoria]&precio_domi=$row1[precio_domi]&precio_plant=$row1[precio_plant]>editar</a>" ?></td> 
      </tr>   
       <?php endwhile; ?>

</table>
```

But they are not linked and I have not much idea on how to do this. im restricted to use php and html only and all similar examples I've found are using javascript or ajax, any idea? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

w/o JavaScript, JQuery, Angular, etc. available, you'll need to submit every time.
So load the page up in its original state, the user will choose their category. Now w/o JS available to go run updates nicely for you, you'll need to submit a form back to the server, then on the server side, get the POST category, and build the desired HTML and send that to the browser to view. This will have to be done every time they change categories.